# SOAP-UI: can one increment a property within the expansion?

Tags: soapui

I have a simple test-request that I keep sending to our application. For testing all the fields can be identical except one - a transactionId - that needs to be different from earlier requests.
I defined a property for that and inserted that into the XML like so:

```
     <ns:transaktionid>${#Project#transaktionid}</ns:transaktionid>
```

... and that works fine. However, I always need to change (typically increment) that property value before sending the next request and that's tedious. I am aware that I could define an additional test-step that could do such computation but I find that a bit complicated. Wouldn't there be an easier solution to this?

Given that one can embedd groovy code in such property expansions I was wondering, if I could not simply auto-increment that property-value.

I thus tried:

```
     <ns:transaktionid>${=(#Project#transaktionid++)}</ns:transaktionid>
```

... which didn't work.
Another attempt was:

```
     <ns:transaktionid>${=(#Project#transaktionid = ${#Project#transaktionid}+1)}</ns:transaktionid>
```

... which didn't work either.

Googling around and lots of trial and errors later I ended up with this working solution:

```
     <ns:transaktionid>${=def project = request.operation.interface.project; project.setPropertyValue("transaktionid", res = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(project.getPropertyValue("transaktionid"))+1)); res}</ns:transaktionid>
```

... but - I mean: come on! Is this really it? Is there *really* no shorter and esp. more elegant solution to achieve this?

Some kind soul with a better idea or a better grasp of the applicable syntax here? Any useful hint would be appreciated!

PS.: I tested the above by defining me a project property "transaktionid", gave it a numerical value, say '10' and then simply sending the above lines to the echo server at "http://httpbin.org/post". In the response there is a field "data" showing you what you sent.

Comment: If you want a random ID then you can use `${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}`

Comment: Good idea, but I would prefer to have incremental numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Groovy script test step that is run after each web service call and updates the property:

```
def txid = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("transaktionid")
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("transaktionid", ${txid + 1})
```

Comment: Is there a central place where one could put that script? All in all we have defined maybe 200 requests. It would be quite an effort to define the above additional step for each.

Comment: It looks like you have two options: Your original expansion in your question, or you can once-off add the steps programmatically, but you will have to try it out till it works: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Creating-groovy-Test-Steps-dynamically-from-setup-script-in/td-p/175155

Comment: Ah - adding these programmatically? That sounds cool! Will give that a try. Thanks! :-)